# Why am i getting an error "package ‘XXXX’ is not available (for R version 3.5.0)" for every package that I am trying to install?

Tags: r, rscript

I have tried

```
install.packages('installr')
```

> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Himanshu Poddar/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     package ‘installr’ is not available (for R version 3.5.0)
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     unable to access index for repository https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.5:
>     cannot open URL 'https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/PACKAGES'

```
install.packages("ghit")
```

> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Himanshu Poddar/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     package ‘ghit’ is not available (for R version 3.5.0)
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     unable to access index for repository https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.5:
>     cannot open URL 'https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/PACKAGES'

Comment: Are you administrator? are you allowed to make changes in the lib folder?

Comment: I cannot reproduce, it installs in my R 3.5.0 (Windows).

Comment: What could be the reason behind mine

Comment: DJV yes I am adminstrator

Comment: Try another mirror? Make sure r can access Internet (e.g firewalls)

Comment: U mean CRAN mirror. Right??. I tried. Didn't get success

Comment: How did it occur? Did it use to work? Did you update your version of R? Is it a fresh install? Is it a personal or a company computer? Can you add some context?

Comment: Don't know how it occurred.I had R 3.5 since beginning. It's a Personal Computer

Comment: `ghit` has been archived on CRAN on May 10th 2018, at the request of its maintainer. You still can get an archived version with `remotes::install_version("ghit", "0.2.18")` (that is, if you can install `remotes` beforehand. Otherwise, you can still grab the archive and install from the targz file

Comment: For `installr`, it is very likely a CRAN mirror issue. I cannot even find stats.ox.ac.uk in the list of public CRAN mirrors. You said you tried another one, but which one? How? Same error?

Comment: It still exists, but it seems it has stopped actually "mirroring" things since 2016

Comment: A robust recommended option is to use cloud.r-project.org ("Automatic redirection to servers worldwide, currently sponsored by Rstudio") like so: `options(repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org")` (set in options for later installations) or specify it manually with `install.packages("installr", repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org")`

Answer (score 0):

Use a working CRAN mirror. The mentioned URLs do indeed not exist (just try with a browser), while for example https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.5 does exist.

Comment: but tabulizer package is not there in it

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar That’s because tabulizer has not been published on CRAN, c.f. https://github.com/ropensci/tabulizer/blob/master/README.md